# Find the general solution for given trigonometric equation

Tags: trigonometry, quadratics

> Find the general solution of:
>
> $$ \sin^2x \cos^2x+\sin x \cos x-1=0 $$

The options are given in the form of $ \tan^{-1} $, so I tried to convert the equation completely in $ \tan $ but was unable to do so.

I also tried using the identity of $ \sin2x $, through which I got

$$ \sin^22x+2\sin2x-4=0 $$

I have got no idea how to proceed further.

Comment: This is a quadratic in $\sin2x$.  Set $u=\sin2x$ if you don't see what I mean.

Comment: @saulspatz I did that and found the value of $\sin2x$ to be $1.23$ and $-3.23$. But the range of sin is from -1 to 1.

Comment: Sorry. There is an option of 'none of these'. I got a bit lazy to check the answer and thought I would get an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now, $$(\sin2x+1)^2=5,$$ which is impossible because $$0\leq (\sin2x+1)^2\leq4.$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

First set $$u\triangleq \sin x\cos x$$to obtain $$u^2+u-1=0$$then solve for $x$ from $u$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but this quadratic equation has $-1\pm\sqrt 5$ as roots, and the absolute value of each of these roots is greater than $1$. Therefore as a trigonometric equation in $x$, it has no root.